# Best way to check if current user can edit their profile in React frontend using an API?

Tags: reactjs, rest, flask, frontend

I am building a website using Flask, and am refactoring my application to use a JSON based API and React frontend.

Currently, using Jinja templating, if a user wants to edit their own profile, the application will check if the user of the desired page is the currently logged in user, and then render the required button:

```html
{% if user == current_user %}
<p><a href="{{ url_for('edit_profile') }}">Edit your profile</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

where user and current_user are objects passed in via Flask's `render_template()`

I am not sure what the best way to do this in React however. I have API endpoints that return user data, and was thinking of adding an additional endpoint to specifically return the current user's data, so that a similar test can be done in JSX/JavaScript:

```js
{user.id == current_user.id &&
    <EditProfileLink>
}
```

where user and current_user are JSON objects obtained via the API.

Does this make sense or is there a more traditional (safer?) pattern to accomplish such a check?

**Edit**: Trying to build off of Osama Bin Saleem's answer - If I have a `get_user()` endpoint which returns user data ( like username etc) should the JSON returned have a `can_edit` boolean that is decided in this API endpoint, in order to affect what renders on the frontend?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [jwt token](https://jwt.io/) based authentication for this. The basic flow would look like this:

1. On login you call a backend endpoint which checks user credentials and generate a jwt token with some expiry duration (you can set the expiration time based on your use case / preference). If the credentials are wrong you return appropriate response i.e http status 403 in this case.
2. Use this jwt in all other API calls after the user has logged in. The jwt token is passed in the request header. The backend can verify and validate if the token is valid or not. If it is valid the operation (edit operation in your case) would be allowed.
3. You should also apply a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) over your routes to secure them. For example, if you need to check that whether the user should be allowed to open the edit page you first verify from the backend that the token is valid. And if it is valid then you redirect the user to the edit page. Otherwise, redirect it to the login page.

Comment: So where exactly in the backend would this take place? I have a `get_user()` endpoint which returns user data ( like username etc) I also have a `update_user()` endpoint for put requests. And while both of these require tokens I don't know how the token can be used to verify that the current user is allowed to edit, and thus render an "edit" button in the frontend.

Comment: Adding to my above comment, should the `get_user()` JSON have a `can_edit` boolean that is decided on the backend, in order to affect what renders on the frontend?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, your every endpoint can have a middlewear which checks if the token is valid or not and if it is, then allow the certain operation. This is a tutorial link for creating middlewears with flask.(https://medium.com/swlh/creating-middlewares-with-python-flask-166bd03f2fd4)

Comment: And yes, you can add can_edit flag as well or assign some role in the DB like "admin" etc which will imply that he can edit his profile. Note that the middlewear to check the token validity will be applied to every endpoint so in that middlewear check you can again to verify if that user has the right permissions or not.

Comment: Followup: you recommend using a higher order component. Would using useContext accomplish the same thing? Since we want to store user data to use it across the application. If not, why a higher order component instead?

Comment: I mean applying HOC on your routes so that you redirect to a certain page only if the user is authenticated. For example: <AppRoute layout={LoggedInLayout} exact path="/profile" component={RequireAuth(UserProfile)} /> . In this Code section, RequireAuth which checks if the user is authenticated or not and redirects to login page if the user is not authenticated.  Also, you can accepts the answer if it answers your question, thanks.

Comment: @BrianBarry If my answer is right for your question then please accept it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers